# How to add static resource files of visualforce page to cache manifest file of HTML5 for offline functionality

Tags: angularjs, html, salesforce, visualforce, html5-appcache

How to add static resource files of visualforce page to cache manifest file of HTML5 for offline functionality in salesforce.

My Resource file structure:

```
AngularApp.resource
--app(folder)
  --app.js
  -controllers
  -views
  -services
  -script 

  AnotherResource.resource
  --.js
  --.js
```

I want to load some of the files from these resources into html5 cache manifest. I have created a manifest vf page as:

CACHE MANIFEST

```
CACHE:
app/controllers/technicianWOController.js
app/controllers/technicianWOListController.js
app/views/technicianWorkOrder.html
app/views/technicianWorkOrderGrid.html
app/app.js
app/Stylesheet/Images
app/script/common.js
app/services

# Resources that require the user to be online.
NETWORK:
*
```

I have referred it in my main VF page as:

```
<apex:page controller="WorkOrderControllerExtension"  docType="html-5.0"  manifest="/apex/CacheManifestVF"
 sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
```

It is not working as expected, I think i am giving wrong path in cache-manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce really hates Cache Manifests. You'll need to set

```
applyHtmlTag="false"
```

then add your own html tag

```
<html manifest="/apex/CacheManifestVF">
```

Open your developer console to confirm, it'll say things about cache events if it's working. If in doubt, look at the first html tag on the page and make sure your manifest file is in there. For reference, the cache manifest I use is

```
<apex:page contentType="text/cache-manifest" applyHtmlTag="false" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">CACHE MANIFEST
{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS103, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js

NETWORK:
*

#</apex:page>
```

Note how the CACHE MANIFEST is on the same line as the page declaration. Especially note the `#` in front of the closing tag. Visualforce puts a script at the end and the `#` marks it as a comment in the cache.

Good luck!